# Add HTML/CSS overlays by text location on pdf document when rendering in pdf.js viewer

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf.js

How can I programmatically:

- overlay HTML/CSS elements over a PDF document rendered in pdf.js, and
- control the part of the document that is shown in the viewport

Using the locations in the native PDF coordinate system?

The goal here is to be able to, for example, highlight all occurrences of a phrase or add interactive design elements that are positioned according to the location of text that I have already parsed out of the document on the back end.

As a specific example, if know the phrase 'This is my Text.' is located on page 4 of my pdf document, and the box defining the position of this text on the page in the [native pdf coordinate system](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v18/dh/to/leadtools.topics.pdf~pdf.topics.pdfcoordinatesystem.html) is

```
bottom left corner = (0,0)
top right corner = (14, 5)
```

Is it possible to 1) scroll down to that line of the document so it is visible, and 2) overlay a div over this location?

I see that this is essentially what the built in 'text search', 'find next', and 'find prev' functionality it doing, but having some trouble interpreting the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PDF.js defines so called [PageViewport](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/shared/util.js#L786) which allows to convert between PDF coordinates and presentation on the screen. To create a viewport see PDF page's [getViewport](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L491). Convert coordinates to on-screen presentation: `var screenRect = viewport.convertToViewportRectangle([0, 0, 14, 5]);` Normalize coordinates and overlay div on the canvas.

API for the generic viewer is not defined yet. However you can get a page view using viewer component: `var pageView = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.getPageView(3); // get page 4 view`. The pageView will have `viewport` and `div`-container. (Since API is not defined yet, names and arguments might change) If you are using viewers containers, please notice that they are periodically cleaned up during zooming/scroll -- draw your stuff after `pagerendered` event.

Scrolling is just showing `pageView.div` at the region `screenRect` in the current view.

```
var pageNumber = 4;
var pdfRect = [0,0,140,150];

var pageView = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.getPageView(pageNumber - 1);
var screenRect = pageView.viewport.convertToViewportRectangle(pdfRect);

var x = Math.min(screenRect[0], screenRect[2]), width = Math.abs(screenRect[0] - screenRect[2]);
var y = Math.min(screenRect[1], screenRect[3]), height = Math.abs(screenRect[1] - screenRect[3]);

// note: needs to be done in the 'pagerendered' event
var overlayDiv = document.createElement('div');
overlayDiv.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);position:absolute;' +
  'left:' + x + 'px;top:' + y + 'px;width:' + width + 'px;height:' + height + 'px;');
pageView.div.appendChild(overlayDiv);

// scroll
scrollIntoView(pageView.div, {top: y});
```

Comment: what is actually this var pdfRect = [0,0,140,150];